# Android directory system

Tags: android

I am a little unsure on how to store and load files on Android.

I know that Assets are stored in `file:///android_assets/`, but this directory is exclusive to every application and read only, right?

Where can/ should I store files that are created on runtime and are exclusive to their app/ should be shared between apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Manifest file use -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then to access external storage use one of methods from the class [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) -

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation of the Context class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). It has several methods that return directories where to put files depending on their nature (private, media, cache, ...).